# Script to delete columns based on list of possible values in row 1

Tags: google-sheets

I would like a script to delete columns in a Google Spreadsheet if the contents match a list of approximately 30 possible text strings. e.g. Custom Variable 1, Custom Variable 3, Custom Variable 9, etc.

I'm new to Google Scripts. I've searched this forum but haven't found a starting point that handles my specific situation -- deleting columns based on a list of string values rather than a single value or value input from a dialogue box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Scott C

Comment: Could you upload a copy spreadsheet as an example. It would be great to show to show the experiments you tried as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're asking, you wish to read through a column and compare a list of values to the value in each row of that column.  If that column contains any one of those 30 values, delete that column.

One way you could do it:

Hard code an array that contains all of those values you have in mind.  Loop over the column you desire, storing each value into an array (So you would have two arrays total when you're done.  One with the hard coded values, the other with the column values).  Then, take those values from Array 2, and see if they match any of the words in Array 1.  If one of those values matches your list, delete that column.